# Fill or inserting new field based on comparison of two other field

Tags: qgis, postgresql, ppygis

I have a layer `Network` with two different columns

```
Route and section
```

I need a query or function that compare `Route` rows , and `section` rows, and create or rather fill the `new_field` with this condition:

```
IF(route.row=route.row-1;"newfieldvalue"=1;
IF(section.row=section.row-1;"newfield_value"+1;1))
```

This Query or function should compare each Coloumn with it selfs that mean:

If the row value of Route is equal to the one above; and if the row value of section couloumn is equal to the one above than insert( @current value of new field + 1) else 1;

Comment: please clarify what you want to compare exactly. also, as it stands, there seems to be no (clear) relation to geographic/spatial data (are `Distance` and `region` supposed to be geometries or sth.?).

Comment: @ThingumaBob : misstype than you , i correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasonable options:

- [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-window.html), namely the `lag(<column_value>,  <row_offset>, <default_value>)` function that returns the `<column_value>` at the  (specified or 1.) row *before* the current row, or, if no such row exists, the `<default_value>` (specified or *NULL*)
- a table [`JOIN LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) with itself, selecting the row with `<row_number - 1>` for each row passed to the join query

In both cases it's substantial to provide a `ORDER BY <value>` clause (for window functions in `OVER()`) to get meaningful references to neighboring rows.

There's still no relation to spatial data here, making this off-topic for this board...